# Copy text using sprintf() into char array - C / Atmel studio 7

Tags: c, string, printf, avr, lcd

I have got the following problem: 
switches shall be pushed and transmit signal via input pins of Port A shifted for 1 position to Port B (worked as planned). now the program shall count the buttons pushed and print that text to a small LCD display.

When I try to save a text to an array using sprintf I get nothing written into the memory location. What am I doing wrong? Note: we should use sprintf for the solution.

```
#include "avr/io.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "lcd.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {
    unsigned char mask, presetb;
    char *text[20];
    unsigned char buttons;

    //variable to save lcd infos
    display myLCD;

    //set pointer to DDRA & set to Input(0)
    DDRA &= ~((1 << DDA2) | (1 << DDA3) | (1 << DDA4) | (1 << DDA5)); //sets bits 2 to 5 to 0

    //set ptr to DDRB and set as output (1)
    DDRB |= ((1 << DDB3) | (1 << DDB4) | (1 << DDB5) | (1 << DDB6)); //sets bits 3 to 6 to 1

    //initialize LCD
    lcd_init(&myLCD, &PORTD);

    for (;;) {
        //set pointer to PINA & read bits 2 to 5, save in 'mask' and shift number <<1
        mask = PINA & ((1 << PIN2) | (1 << PIN3) | (1 << PIN4) | (1 << PIN5));
        mask = mask << 1;

        //set ptr to PORTB and copy shifted number
        presetb = (~((1 << PIN3) | (1 << PIN4) | (1 << PIN5) | (1 << PIN6))) & (PORTB); //save bitvalues of bits 0 - 2 and 7
        PORTB = (mask | presetb); //copy bits 0-2 and 7 of 'presetb' and bits 3 -6 of 'mask' to PORTB

        //number of buttons pressed
        buttons = 0;

        if (PINB3 == 1)
            buttons += 1;

        if (PINB4 == 1)
            buttons += 1;

        if (PINB5 == 1)
            buttons += 1;

        if (PINB6 == 1)
            buttons += 1;

        //set string
        sprintf(*text, "Pushed Buttons %d", (unsigned char)buttons);

        //print text "Pushed Buttons [Nbr]"
        lcd_send_string(&myLCD, *text, 1, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `char *text[20];` is an array of twenty uninitialized *pointers*

Comment: Note: Don't use the stream-functions on AVR or similar MCUs. They are far too clumsy and bloat. Write your own small conversion functions.

Comment: You are confusing arrays and pointers.

Comment: You need to implement signal debouncing to dodge the electro-mechanical bounce you get from all buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *text[20];
```

is an array of 20 pointers to `char`. In line

```
sprintf(*text, "Pushed Buttons %d", (unsigned char) buttons);
```

you are trying to use `sprintf` to put text into `*text`, which is first entry of array, a pointer to char. Uninitialized pointer.

What you want is

```
char text[20];
sprintf(text, "Pushed Buttons %d", (unsigned char) buttons);
```

an array of 20 characters.

Answer (score 1):

text should be

```
char text[20];
```

Take off the *

Comment: ` sprintf(*text, ...` should be modified to ` sprintf(text, ...` as well

Comment: Good catch @chqrlie , and the * needs to be removed from lcd_send_string(&myLCD, *text, 1, 1);

Comment: @tinky_winky: `%u` is not actually required: `(unsigned char)buttons` is implicitly converted and passed as an `int`.